# Graph terminology

Tags: terminology

If $B$ is the subgraph of $A$, can we say $A$ is the "parent" graph or the "original" graph?

Context: 
"In a subgraph, the vertices and edges are a subset of the **parent** graph."

Not sure if it's right since we're not dealing with trees.

Comment: I am not sure that I have ever seen such terminology used, but that doesn't mean that you can't use it.  The parent / child analogy makes sense (though it might cause confusion in the case of a tree, where parent / child nodes are often said to exist).  You could also say "supergraph" (the sub / super pairing is common in mathematics), and I think that the language "containing graph" would probably be clear.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory_terms ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term you want is [*supergraph*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Supergraph.html):

> **supergraph:** If $G'$ is a subgraph of $G$, then $G$ is said to be a supergraph of $G'$.

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty here is that there are an infinite number of graphs for which $B$ is a subgraph.  There is no *unique* parent graph $A$.

I think it is best to simply say "graph."

If you've described that $B$ is a subgraph of $A$ and that is the graph you wish to mention, just say "$A$."